# Does a mojo-pipeline automatically drop columns as specified during training?

Tags: python, driverless-ai

I have ran a DAI experiment & built the mojo-pipeline. Now I have brand new data with columns I originally dropped within the DAI GUI; ID column for example. Does the mojo-pipeline automatically drop these columns when scored or do I need to do this prior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mojo-pipeline will ignore all columns that weren't used for training - that includes columns that were dropped in DAI and any new columns they may have been introduced into the data.

Comment: Great, thanks Joe. To clarify it sounds like if I have x initial columns during training & building the pipeline, then have x + n columns within a new csv, the mojo-pipeline will know to subset the x + n to x during scoring.
Essentially, as long as I have the original columns somewhere in the new data, DAI will figure it out and drop the rest, correct?